# Add custom product data using javascript when add to cart button is clicked

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to add custom data to the cart using javascript? The data is from URL query params. I have tried using `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` and setting query-vars etc, but my data is not populated at the time I click the add to cart button. I am thinking maybe the `$( document.body ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );` event but I am not sure how to go about adding the url params as extra data. Here is my code so far.

```
$(document.body).on('adding_to_cart', function(  button, data ) {
            const queryString = window.location.search;
            const urlParams  = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            //the url params that i want to add as custom cart data
            var color = urlParams.get('color'),
                hexcode = urlParams.get('hex'),
                extracost = urlParams.get('price')    
        })
```

Comment: Is JavaScript a requirement?

Comment: Not really.  I had resorted to javascript because ```woocommerce_add_cart_item_data``` returns my query params as null

Comment: And you're adding to cart from the single product page? So the URL is like e.g. example.com/product/whateverproduct?color=red&hex=112244&extracost=11 ?

Comment: No this is not from the single products page.

Comment: Ok then if you could explain better the context, and also post a sample URL so that I can come up with something :)

Comment: Ok. So the user selects a color that they want. The browser then redirects to a page which shows products available in that color. The url will be something like example.com/?color=red&hexcod=#ff0000&extracost=15. So on clicking the add to cart button, I wanted to associate these url params with the product clicked.

Comment: What if its variation product and color is just one of the params ? How you gonna add it to cart without size for example ?

Comment: Ok thanks for that. re: add to cart URLs: are they a href buttons, or are they input fields in a form?